# Difference between "Dickicht" and "Gestrüpp"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "Dickicht" and "Gestrüpp"? To what degree are the two words synonymous?
Are there certain situations where these words would not be used?

Comment: Was sagt das Wörterbuch?

Comment: No effort was shown in this question. Guesses, even wrong ones, are fine, because they give us a starting point from which to work (and a clue to you proficiency). But there is no such Standpunkt here. You haven't made clear, for instance, that these words refer to "plants" (or that you intend another meaning).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Das Gestrüpp** is something you can entangle yourself in. It does not necessarily mean you cannot see your way.

> Meine Beine steckten in dem Gestrüpp fest.

*My legs were stuck in the brushwood.*

**Das Dickicht** is something you cannot see through.

> Sie verschwanden ins Dickicht.

*They disappeared into the covert.*

Comment: Wenn man hindurchsehen kann, ist es eher ein Dünnicht.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Good idea, let's confuse the learners with cringe-worthy puns, why not? For the record: There's no such word.

Comment: If I google images for *Dickicht*, most scenes are quite "transparent", but the *Gestrüpp* images [are spot on (example)](http://www.sonyuserforum.de/galerie/data/media/838/DSC00303.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

*Gestrüpp* targets the plants themselves that make up the scrub without specifying what types of plants (thorns, blackberries, ...) it's consisting of, but differentiating from "trees", "bushes", "grass".

You can

- das Gestrüpp zurückschneiden
- sich am Gestrüpp die Beine aufscheuern
- das Gestrüpp ausreißen

Also, *Gestrüpp* denotes scrubby, thorny plants, hard to **go through**.

*Dickicht* targets the *group of plants* as a thicket and denotes the type of vegetation (differentiating from "wood", "meadow", "grassland",...)

You can

- Ein Reh im Dickicht verschwinden sehen
- sich im Dickicht verstecken

*Dickicht* denotes a vegetation type that is **hard to see through**, not necessarily hard to go through. (Could also be just ferns instead of scrubs and thorns)

So, the difference between "Gestrüpp" and "Dickicht" is very much the same difference as the one between "Bäume" and "Wald", i.e. "trees" and "forest".

You thus *cannot* use the following sentences

- Ich lasse das Dickicht hinten im Garten nächstes Jahr ausreißen
- Ich habe mir am Dickicht die Beine aufgescheuert
- Der Förster hat draußen im Wald ein Dickicht angepflanzt

You would rather use "Gestrüpp" in this context.

*Gestrüpp*, denoting the sort of thorny, physically scrubby plants, also doesn't work for some types of thickets: *Im Dickicht des Schilfs* (reed thicket) and *im Dickicht des Farns* (fern thicket) work OK, while *Schilfgestrüpp* (reed scrub) and *Farngestrüpp* don't - *Gestrüpp* doesn't fit for fern and reed.

Answer (score 2):

For German we have the "Duden" as famous reference for German words and explanations. It seems to make no difference between the two words [Dickicht (Duden)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Dickicht) and [Gestrüpp](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gestruepp). It even mentions it synonymously in the first link.

Personally I would say that "Dickicht" is a more literal / old style word, whereas "Gestrüpp" might be slang / gossip. But you would find it in either of them and everybody will understand.

You might also find the word "Unterholz" interesting. Hope that helps.

Comment: The "Duden" (I assume that you mean "Duden, Vol. 1") is primarily an *orthographical* wordbook, not a general dictionary, even though sometimes short explanations are given.

Answer (score 1):

A *»Dickicht«* usually is a dark, jungle-like area which can be entered by man.
A *»Gestrüpp«* is a small size *»Dickicht«* which cannot be entered by the whole of your body. The man with the machete is typically not found inside a *»Gestrüpp«*.

> - Er verschwand im Dickicht des Waldes.
> - Wer seinen Garten zu lange nicht pflegt, steht knietief im Gestrüpp.
> - Wenn der Mann seinen Intimbereich nicht rasiert, entsteht ein Gestrüpp
>     (Vogelnest).

Answer (score 1):

By way of confirmation what others have said here about the difference of *Dickicht* and *Gestrüpp*, here an erotic short story (very short!) that includes and illustrates both:

> Meine Freundin und ich gingen in den Wald, um uns im **Dickicht** versteckt ein paar schöne Stunden zu machen. Doch wir verfingen uns im **Gestrüpp** und kamen ganz zerkratzt heraus.

You cannot swap *Dickicht* and *Gestrüpp* here. Which is a nice indicator that they are indeed not synonyms.